# Port Fowarding port 80

Tags: apache, xampp, port, router

I attempted to forward the port 80. I went to canyouseeme.org to test if it works or not, and it said success. After that once I tried to access it from my public IP, it did not work. It showed me my router cPanel. I use xampp for the apache service.

Comment: Then the port forwarding wasn't set up properly. Check it again. Perhaps you need to restart the router?

Comment: I dont think thats the problem because the port is visible at canyouseeme.org, so it should obviously work. my router is D-Link DSL 2750-U Also I can access my site from 192.168.1.12 it works fine, but my public IP is the problem.

Comment: Well, Canyouseeme.org likely sees the router's control panel and thinks it's your web site. It can't see whether port forwarding is configured internally.

Comment: Mm I tried a restart, what do I do now? It still doesnt work. :[ I even restarted my computer, I did make sure that I disabled the firewall + disabled my AVG Firewall.

Comment: I don't know that router, so I can't tell where the problem is. All I can think of is make super sure the port forwarding is set up correctly. Port 80 needs to point to 192.168.1.12 and this needs to be configured in the router

Comment: For apache, port 80 can be changed from httpd.conf. After changing the port, Rebuild apache conf file or restart apache service to make it into effect. Otherwise you can make use of iptable routing for forwarding the port.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also enabled port 80 in port triggering and now it works fine on my DLink Router.